# Где узнать о правилах русского языка?

Tags: правописание

Где узнать о правилах русского языка, актуальных на данный момент?

В инженерном деле когда речь идёт о формальностях, например о правилах искусственного языка (например для написания компьютерных программ), то люди создают спецификации. Этими спецификациями владеет или большие ассоциации такие как IEEE/ISO или большие и влиятельные организации.

Так вот где находится официальная спецификация, что считать верным, а что нет в рамках естественного языка, который используется официально на территории Российского государства?

Comment: Русский язык не принадлежит и не управляется Российской Федерацией. В других государствах он тоже может иметь официальный статус. На территории РФ самой авторитетной организаций считается [Институт русского языка имени В. В. Виноградова](http://ruslang.ru/).

Comment: @SergeyKirienko если вы немного расширите свой комментарий - мне вот кажется - это годится даже в ответы

Comment: регулирующего органа как такового нет

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на  институт русского языка В.В. Виноградова. С английским языком тоже самое http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26749/english-language-formal-specification

Comment: На практике, может быть http://rosental-book.ru/.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень полезная ссылка. Хоть и изначальная постановка вопроса была про точку отсчёта.

Answer (score 4):

Вот приказ Минобрнауки России "Об утверждении списка грамматик, словарей и справочников, содержащих нормы современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка Российской Федерации":

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/docs?layout=item&id=16_12

Негусто, но хоть что-то.

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia, the [Russian Language Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Language_Institute) (Институт русского языка имени В. В. Виноградова РАН) is the regulator for the Russian language.

Answer (score -5):

В русском языке нет спецификаций, в рамках естественного языка все познается на ходу/everything is figured out "on the run". Все правила как в старых учебниках, так и новых одинаковы абсолютно.