# Допустимы ли выражения "на эмоциях" и "на характере" с точки зрения норм русского языка?

Tags: стилистика, грамотность

Довольно часто стали попадаться в речи и в письме эти выражения. Примеры употребления:

> «Одержал победу на характере»
>
> «Принял решение на эмоциях»
>
> «Совершил поступок на кураже»

и т.д.

На мой взгляд, эти выражения (в особенности «на характере») звучат довольно просторечно и убого. Что «говорят» нормы русского языка про такие обороты? Допустимы ли они, или их следует перефразировать?

Comment: "На характере" для меня выглядит странно и непонятно, остальные ОК.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Этот ответ приходится давать часто, но поскольку вопросы-то разные - а ответ один и тот же - я не думаю, что можно такие вопросы закрывать. Возможно, впрочем, имеет это обсудить с комьюнити и модифицировать правила.

Ну так вот - есть фактическое применение каких-то грамматических конструкций и фразеологизмов - и это фактическое применение существует без оглядки на какие-то бы ни было нормативные нормы. Как неоднократно уже отмечалось на этом стеке - единого регулятора русского языка не существует, но даже если б он существовал - это не отменило бы реального словоупотребления.

Говорят `на районе`? Да, говорят. `На измене` говорят, `на стиле` говорят. 
Это просто факт. Мы его можем констатировать. Другое дело, что так же мы, как наблюдатели, можем констатировать и тот факт, что это всё часть разговорного языка (и часто молодёжного сленга, например) - но в газете, официальном документе эти формы не употребляются.

Все приведённые вами примеры легальны хотя бы потому, что существуют. 
Более того, их применение куда менее маргинально, чем это может показаться. Говорим же мы `на честном слове`, например. `На одном кураже далеко не уедешь` - тоже вполне литературная фраза.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Совершенно понятно, что невозможно регламентировать использование и развитие разговорного языка. Меня скорее интересовало, есть ли какие-то правила в «официальном» языке, которые могли бы объяснить и/или оправдать использование таких конструкций. В принципе, на это я тоже получил ответ.

Comment: Мне все же кажется, что вопрос стоит "расслоить" на нормы русского языка вообще, "официальные" и "литературные" нормы (которые шире "официальных"). "На одном кураже", например - это другая форма, чем просто "на кураже", последняя, возможно, неуместна в литературе.

Comment: "единого регулятора русского языка не существует" - существует.

Comment: @Anixx - давайте избегать лишнего информационного шума. Вот вы написали  - "существует". Понятно же, что закономерно будет вас спросить, например,  - "а кого вы считаете регулятором - институт русского языка имени Виноградова?" - и снова ждать ответа. А можно, например, сразу сказать - "существует - такой-то".

Comment: В официальной сфере язык регулирует государство: https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/14174/2104

Comment: "На измене", "на кураже" и даже "на честном слове" подразумевает некое "изменённое состояние сознание", какую-то крайне сильную эмоцию, заменяющую рациональный расчёт пользы. "на районе", "на деревне" - другой шаблон, хотя я затрудняюсь сформулировать его цели и границы. Но "на стиле"? ни рыба ни мясо. Что это выражает, зачем?...